# Not able to install Django on windows 7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to install Django-1.5.5 on windows 7. I have installed it but when I try to punch in "django-admin.py startproject mysite" I get following error:

```
C:\Users\DIPANSHU>django-admin.py startproject mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Django-1.5.5\django\bin\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
9, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError, han
fault_options
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", lin
in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import force_str
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 10,
dule>
    from urllib import quote
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Previously, I tried with Django-1.4.2 but problem was same. I am having Python27.Please assist.

Comment: how did you install Django? using PIP?

Comment: I downloaded it from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django/1.4 unzipped it run the command:
    python setup.py install

Comment: I would recommend installing Django with a python install manager, such as pip. If you have the newest version of python it should've come with pip out of the box (i think 3.4 and later include pip). Make sure you already have the Scripts directory from your Python installation directory in your system's environment variable Path, and run pip install Django from the cmd

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with your Python install (not Django). How did you install Python? Do you have the correct version for your OS? 32-bit vs. 64-bit?

Comment: Yups! Finally got it! Si here's what I did:

Answer (score 1):

Yups! Finally got it! So here's what I did:

1. Removed python completely and installed it again.
2. adjust my PATH environment variable to include paths to the Python executable & additional scripts.
3. Installed Setuptools
4. Installed pip using easy_install pip.
5. Installed Django using pip install django.

Note: If your Python is installed in `C:\Python27\`, the following paths need to be added to `PATH: C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;`

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/windows/

Thanks a lot for your valuable inputs and bearing with me! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that DJango is installed by running

python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

I found the Django tutorial on their site to be very good

Also what exactly are you typing into the command prompt ? You should simply be in directory C:\Users\DIPANSHU> in the command shell

EDIT: you should be in the directory where you installed Django

Comment: I checked that as well. Seems fine. This is what I get:                                              C:\Users\DIPANSHU>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] o
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import django
    >>> django.VERSION
    (1, 5, 5, 'final', 0)

Comment: This sounds like django is installed but must not be unpacking correctly. Possibly follow the advice from fr1tz above. I also used PIP to install Django and had some trouble but it worked out in the end.